# How to find the first two and last two character of string without using string function and array function in PHP

Tags: php

I have a string

```
$str = 'Mukesh Dubey';
```

I want o/p : `Mu Du`

Without using array and string function of `PHP`

Comment: How is `Du` last 2 characters? And any specific reason why not to use string functions?

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to use `preg_replace` with the regex pattern `([A-Z][a-z])\S+`, and then replace with just the captured first two letters.

```
$str = 'Mukesh Dubey';
$output = preg_replace("/([A-Z][a-z])\S+/", "$1", $str);
echo $str . "\n" . $output;
```

This prints: `Mu Du`

Trivially, to cater to retaining any two starting letters, regardless of case, we can try:

```
$str = 'wolly dolly';
$output = preg_replace("/([A-Za-z]{2})\S+/", "$1", $str);
echo $str . "\n" . $output;
```

Comment: @MukeshDubey  it will not work for small letters:- https://3v4l.org/bSTs9

Comment: @AnantSingh---AlivetoDie Why are you pointing out a trivial edge case?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  because i don't want that after sometime OP will ask you for the same what i have mentioned.